# Skip group rows when adding recordnumbers

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I have the following code to add 'recordnumbers' in a cxGrid but it has the unwanted sideefeect that if it is a grid with grouping then it step one number every time there is a GroupRow and then there is a missing number.
Any ways to avoid this

```
procedure TfrmProjectTasksActive.colCountGetDisplayText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AText: string);
var
  Row: integer;
begin
  Row := Sender.GridView.DataController.GetRowIndexByRecordIndex(aRecord.RecordIndex, False);
  aText := Format('%.*d', [3, (Row + 1)]);;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the number of groups before the row should work then, something like:

```
procedure TfrmProjectTasksActive.colCountGetDisplayText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AText: string);
var
  Row, GrIdx: integer;
begin
  Row   := Sender.GridView.DataController.GetRowIndexByRecordIndex(aRecord.RecordIndex, False);
  GrIdx := Sender.GridView.DataController.Groups.DataGroupIndexByRowIndex[Row] + 1;
  aText := Format('%.*d', [3, (Row + 1 - GrIdx)]);
end;
```

You need the `+1` in the `GrIdx` because when there is no groups then group index is `-1`, first group has a index `0` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested, written out of memory...):

```
procedure TfrmProjectTasksActive.colCountGetDisplayText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AText: string);
var
  Row: integer;
  aRowInfo : TcxRowInfo;
begin
  aRowInfo := ARecord.GridView.DataController.GetRowInfo(ARecord.Index);
  if not (aRowInfo.Level < ARecord.GridView.DataController.Groups.GroupingItemCount) then //test, if Row is not a group-row
  begin
    Row := Sender.GridView.DataController.GetRowIndexByRecordIndex(aRecord.RecordIndex, False);
    aText := Format('%.*d', [3, (Row + 1)]);
  end;
end;
```

Hope I have it in my mind correctly, sorry if it does not work out of the box. But the "aRowInfo" should at least give you the right hint... Also: pay attention to the difference between "Index" and "RecordIndex" of the "ARecord".

Comment: Not working right off the box - but the next solution does so I will use that